# How does Spring use Java 8 classes, yet it runs on Java 7?

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I recently downloaded the source code for the Spring MVC (Version 4.0.2.RELEASE) module within the Spring Framework.  My intention is to run against the actual source code for the module instead of the actual `.jar` file. (Long story, only for testing purposes).

After downloading the source code, I removed the `jar` file from my project, compiled and deployed to the server.  When I hit one of the URLs handled by the dispatcher servlet I was presented with the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import java.time cannot be resolved
    The method toZoneId() is undefined for the type TimeZone
    ZoneId cannot be resolved
```

After some research and digging into the source code I realized the class mentioned in the error is part of JDK/JRE 1.8.  Before removing the `.jar` file my project ran without issue on JDK/JRE 1.7.

My question is how does Spring include classes from JDK 1.8, yet still manage to run under JDK/JRE 1.7?  Why is the exception not thrown when using Spring's `.jar` file, but it is thrown when I provide the source (and the jar file is missing)?

**Full Stack Trace**

```
Mar 26, 2014 7:27:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet dispatcher
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import java.time cannot be resolved
    The method toZoneId() is undefined for the type TimeZone
    ZoneId cannot be resolved

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.<init>(ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.java:23)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.getDefaultArgumentResolvers(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:522)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1274)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? That class does not seem to have those imports.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The class is `ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver`, I will post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the headline question is: Spring builds with Java 8, but is compatible with Java 7 (and 6).

`ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver` does import `java.time.ZoneId`, but it only refers to that class in a nested class which isn't instantiated unless Java 8 is on the classpath. There are many examples like this in Spring source code (always have been, e.g. since it started supporting Java 5).

Comment: Yes, obviously, if you really must compile it. What's wrong with the jar that ships from Spring?

Comment: As I said long story and I don't condone this!  Basically, I'm being asked to scan the Spring Framework to ensure that it is secure.  Would be interested to hear your thoughts about that.

Comment: @KevinBowersox scan spring to ensure its secure :) good luck Kevin

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh Once again, not my idea!

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh I am not jealous of that job but that is what makes Open Source software interesting. Glad to here that it happens from time to time.